# Install happstack-server 6.5.3 on osx - missing libcryptopp

Tags: macos, haskell, macports

I'm trying to install the latest happstack-server on osx. They just added a dependency on libcryptopp, and I can't get it working.

```
~$ cabal install happstack-server
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring happstack-server-6.5.3...
cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: cryptopp
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
happstack-server-6.5.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

So, then I install libcryptopp with macports, which puts libcryptopp.a in /opt/local/lib

```
sudo port install libcryptopp
```

Then I install happstack-server again with --extra-lib-dirs

```
cabal install happstack-server --extra-lib-dirs=/opt/local/lib
```

It installs fine, everything seems to work until I actually *run* a happstack server.

```
~$ runhaskell Hello.hs
Hello.hs: <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: libcryptopp.dylib (dlopen(libcryptopp.dylib, 9): image not found)
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug with happstack? I don't even have a .dylib after installing the lib via macports, only a .a. `ghc --make Hello.hs` [is even crazier](https://gist.github.com/1683089)

Comment: The `Hello.hs` errors are probably due to the wrong `iconv` library. I keep forgetting which, but I think the system one doesn't work with Haskell, you need to install the macports `iconv`. Or the other way round. Mac is a bit of a mess because there are so many different ways to install packages and places where they go, it seems. But if you figured that out, I hear it works nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a brute-force approach, You can disable https flag in .cabal file of `happstack-server`:

**file: happstack-server.cabal** :

```
Flag https
    Default: False
```

configure/build/install `happstack-server` manually, them `cabal install happstack`.

---

(I use Archlinux, --extra-lib-dirs don't even work!)

Comment: Note I didn't actually try this, but I assume it works. I switched app servers instead :)

Comment: @Sean Clark Hess: You're write, I tried `happstack-server` 6.4.*, that works. :)

Answer (score 7):

How about:

`g++  -fpic -nostartfiles -nostdlib -shared /usr/local/Cellar/cryptopp/5.6.1/lib/libcryptopp.a -o libcryptopp.dylib`

Comment: Thanks! This is much better than trying to fix the problem in the cryptopp make files directly!